# JavaMail Api on Android Issues

Tags: android, email

Good Day.

Im developing huge program and now I'm stuck in **e-mail** part.

I want user to type on a field an information,afterwards hit "`SEND E-MAIL`" Button and don't interact no more.By idea my application  should send what user typed automatically without asking recipient or users *password/e-mail*.I tried to achieve that by integrating JavaMail api in android but failed and i have no clue why!!I tried all possible source codes in WHOLE internet which available for javaMail Api for android but none of them send e-mail and most of them giving error which won't show on error `logCat` car.So please can you tell me the most easy way to do it,but without intent of android I'm again stuck in this simple think...

Thanks a lot beforehand

Comment: Why do you want to use java Mail Api, when android provide this in very easy way by using Intent Uri?

Comment: See intent asking for recipient but my application should not ask for it and it should send not from default client email address but by address i provide in my application thats it.in short user only must type information and have no interaction no more just click send button thats all

Comment: Then fetch email address from your app and pass it in place of recipient address in Intent.

Comment: Ok give you a case- and what if user don't have default e-mail client configured in android?he shouldn't waste time for it,its minus for my application.I can fetch,but most of users don't configure default mailing client

Comment: Now you think what will happen when we don't put recipient address while sending email?
When user not set any default email then before sending email you have to put a check that address should not be null and not be empty.

Comment: You don't understand me.lets pretend its a feedback.Application have its own default e-mail (must have) which is a company e-mail,and from that e-mail onClick he must give feedback information

Comment: or even we can make anonymous one,its better for user even! he won't give any additional information about his e-mail just only he one he prefer thats best and thats why i can't use intent